# How to remove the out of stock products on checkout page from order and display them

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the out of stock products from the order on checkout page. The idea is:

1. A product is added to cart (out of stock product)
2. The user goes to the checkout page
3. The product which is out of stock will be removed from the order and displayed in popup with details about the removed product

Currently what I was able to do is, the out of stock products are being removed on the checkout page and the popup is displayed, showcasing the products which were removed. But when the checkout page is reloaded again the fields are disoriented and the whole page layout is disturbed.

The following code is checking for and removing the out of stock products.

```
  $removed_products = [];
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product_obj = $cart_item['data'];

        if ( ! $product_obj->is_in_stock() ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            $removed_products[] = $product_obj;
        }
    }
```

Please check the following screenshot.
[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q22sl45pix8nw1t/Checkout%20page%20issue.png?dl=0)

Comment: When a product is 'out of stock'. How can it be added to the shopping cart? By default the add to cart button is hidden at 'out of stock' products. Suppose it wouldn't be. Why not immediately prevent these products from being added as opposed to removing them afterwards?

Comment: Thanks @7uc1f3r for your suggestion, the products are allowed to be added in cart on the basis of back orders. But the removal function is required to make user experience better.